# Discrete generalization of Fibonacci golden ratios?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I have found the connection of :

---

$$
a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}
$$
$$
A = \lim_{n \to \infty} \biggl( \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \biggr)
$$
$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_1 = 1$$

---

$$
b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + b_{n-3}
$$
$$
B = \lim_{n \to \infty} \biggl( \frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}} \biggr)
$$
$$b_0 = 1$$
$$b_1 = 1$$
$$b_2 = 1$$

---

$$
c_n = c_{n-1} + c_{n-2} + c_{n-3} + c_{n-4}
$$
$$
C = \lim_{n \to \infty} \biggl( \frac{c_n}{c_{n-1}} \biggr)
$$
$$c_0 = 1$$
$$c_1 = 1$$
$$c_2 = 1$$
$$c_3 = 1$$

---

It seems that A, B, C is a root of :
$$A \rightarrow a^1 + a^2 = a^3$$
$$B \rightarrow a^1 + a^2 + a^3 = a^4$$
$$C \rightarrow a^1 + a^2 + a^3 + a^4 = a^5$$

---

How can I prove it ?

---

Update nr 1

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{m} x ^ n = \frac{x (x^m - 1)}{x - 1} = x ^ {m+1}
$$
$$
\frac{(x - 2) x^m + 1}{x - 1} = 0
$$

Comment: Have you tried diagonalising?

Comment: It follows from the general theory of linear [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

Answer (score 3):

For any recurrent relation
$$
a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + \ldots + a_{n-k}
$$
we can find $k$ geometric progressions that will satisfy this relation. Indeed,$a_n = \lambda^n$,  where $\lambda$ is a root of characteristic polynomial $\lambda^k = \lambda^{k-1} + \lambda^{k-2} + \ldots + \lambda +1$
satisfies the recurrent relation.

It can be shown that general solution is
$$
a_n = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \lambda_i^n, 
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the roots of characteristic polynomial, $c_i$ are constants that can be found from the condition
$$
a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_k = 1.
$$
Without losing of generality let $c_1 \neq 0$ and $|\lambda_1| = \max_{i} |\lambda_i|$. Then assuming $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ for $i \neq j$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k c_i \lambda_i^{n+1}}{\sum_{i=1}^k c_i \lambda_i^{n}} = \lambda_1.
$$